# Use JS library with Django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a problem using a js library with django. I am trying to use the [particle.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) library to generate a particle background for the home page and I have tried following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK3cgD09Qf0).

I have created a `particle.json` and `style.css` in my static folder.

UPDATED VERSION (with static files)

**home.html**

```
<!-- templates/home.html --> 
{% load socialaccount %}
{% load account %} 
{% load static %}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"> </head>

<body>
    <div id="particles-js">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p>


        <a href="/accounts/logout/" >Logout</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'github' %}">Log In with Github</a>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'twitter' %}">Log In with Twitter</a>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' %}">Log In with Facebook</a>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'linkedin' %}">Log In with LinkedIn</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.2/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', '{% static 'particles.json' %}', function(){
            console.log('particles.json loaded...');
        });
    </script> </body>
```

defined the static path in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'artemis/static')
]
```

and im my `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url('', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

When i start the server, I get the following errors in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED
Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined
```

The project structure:

[image]

I just started learning django so I know this might sound like a stupid question but any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why you don't see any error, but pretty sure it cannot find *particles.json*, or your *styles.css* files, as they shouldn't be in your templates folder. Those are static files and you need to make sure you place them in a directory that can be found by your server for static files. Look at [how to manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django can not parse the remainder:

`{% static style.css %}` this should be `{% static 'style.css' %}` with quotes

`{% static particles.json %}` should be `{% static 'particles.json' %}` with quotes

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That solved indeed the first problem but I am still getting the 2nd error 'particlesJS is not defined'. The background now is red but the particles don't appear since it can't see the js

Comment: post this line of code in comment, let me see how you do it

Comment: do you have this `particles.json` in your static directory?

Comment: yes, `particles.json` is in my static directory. Is it possible to load a js script directly from the source? (as I have loaded the `particles.min.js`) or should this be in the static folder as well?

Comment: I added the particles.min.js in my static directory as well and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I saw that people use to have it inside assets like `assets/particles.json`.. static is the root directory based on `settings`, you can set any path as soon as you do it with `/`.. for instance, if you had inside `static`, a directory named `css`, and inside it, you have `style.css`, the path would be `'/static/css/style.css'` -->`{% static 'css/style.css' %}`

Comment: glad to be of help!